# Inherit Index from RepeatControl in nested custom controls

Tags: xpages

I have a Xpage with a repeat control. The index name is set. In the repeat is another custom control. Now a want the index in the nested custom control.
Is the only way to fill out a composite data?

I must unique a div class in the nested custom control. Is that the right way?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All components in an XPage are loaded initially as a tree hierarchy, the component tree. Any component has access to any element upwards and outwards from that branch. So if a custom control is nested inside a repeat, it has access to the repeat row and the variables relating to that row. So if you define the property `indexVar="idex"`, just as any component on that row will resolve the variable name `idex` as the current row index, the same is true for a custom control nested in a row.

As long as `indexVar` has the same variable name in any XPage in which you nest the custom control, you don't have to pass the variable.

Comment: perfect explanation, as always. Just a remark, though: with custom controls there's always a chance that they might be used somewhere else, i.e. in a "place" where there's no "idex" available. That's why I usually prefer to explicitly pass any external values into the CC using compositeData

Comment: For that purpose, I would probably make use of a design definition, explicitly specifying any variable names you need to have in the enclosing custom control / XPage. As ever, design definition helps ensure the enclosing custom controls and XPages load quicker. I've not tested 100% where those variables get stored. It could be in requestScope, in which case it would be possible to "intercept and set the value".

Comment: interesting; what do you mean regarding variables in the context of design definitions? Did I probably miss something here? - edit: some googling brought up some insight into this topic, e.g. http://dontpanic82.blogspot.de/2010/01/xpages-using-powerful-design-definition.html. Very interesting, indeed!

Comment: I was just thinking of e.g. a Label in the design definition that days "REQUIRES VARIABLE "idex" CORRESPONDING TO CURRENT REPEAT ROW INDEX"